# Is it appropriate to post a question about code which has already been reviewed?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I posted some code.  Code Reviewers left me some great suggestions and helped me to drastically improve my code.

Is it appropriate to repost the updated code to get some additional feedback?

Comment: I closed as duplicate, but note that what you want to do is listed in the answer - yes, feel free to post the revised code as a new question. We encourage that.

Comment: Sorry and thanks.  I did search before posting.  Just never came across that one.

Comment: what you are asking is an answer to the other question, so it is understandable that you didn't find it easily. glad to hear that you searched before posting though!  Welcome to Meta.CodeReview!